# For DelayedExpansion Variables Values get stored

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'll try my best to explain my problem. I want to rewrite a file that contains:

If "!Var!" ....

I am rewriting it in a temp file in a for-loop with DelayedExpansion Enabled (I need it enabled to set the !Var! value in the loop), but as soon as he get to the line that cantains that text shown above it writes:

If "Value of Var" ....

So I tried to Disable and then Enable the Expansion while I run ((echo %%a)>>"Temp.File"), but then it says maximum SetLocal reached.

Please help

Rudi

Comment: You changed the entire question.  Why didn't you open a new question?

Comment: Because I didn't ask the question right from the beginning...

Comment: I just want to know how to write the Variable name !Var! in a for command and not it's value while DelayedExpansion is Enabled

Answer (score 1):

```
(for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "%inputFile%"') do (
  if %%a lss %begin% ( echo(%%b
  ) else if %%a gtr %end% echo(%%b
)) > "%tempFile%"
```

Use findstr to numerate the lines of the input file. Numbers are separated from content via `tokens` and `delimiters` clauses of `for` command. If number is out of range, echo the line content. All output is redirected to temporary file

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem..Is my question never gonna be asnwered?

Comment: @user3245536, the answer is to a question you made before i answered, answer that were posted before you changed the question. Include the problematic code and then, maybe, a solution to it could be found.